# AdMob after ad play video

Tags: android, admob

i add admob to my application, so my i want that the application play the video directly after the ad end without to press play.
Because the ad paused the video.

Here is my Code:

```
private InterstitialAd Interstitial;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.video);

    Interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
    Interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

    Interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
        public void onAdClosed(){
            requestNewInterstitial();
            beginVideoStream();
        }
    });
    requestNewInterstitial();

    Interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            if (Interstitial.isLoaded()) {
                Interstitial.show();
            } else {
                beginVideoStream();
            }
        }
    });

    beginVideoStream();
}


private void requestNewInterstitial() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
              .build();

    Interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
}

protected void displayInterstitial() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
public void onDismissScreen() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
public void onFailedToReceiveAd() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
public void onLeaveApplication() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
public void onPresentScreen() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

private void beginVideoStream(){
    VideoView vidView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

    String vidAddress = "http://cdn.ebound.com/14/playlist.mp4";
    Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);

    vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri);
    vidView.start();

    MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(this);
    vidControl.setAnchorView(vidView);
    vidView.setMediaController(vidControl);
}
```

Hope anybody can help me thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks almost correct except by calling `beginVideoStream()` in `onCreate()` you are starting your video and then when the ad cannot be loaded or has been closed you are starting the video again.

That is probably what is pausing your video.

You shouldn't be starting it in `onCreate()`